# Installing XCode 5 on OS X 10.7?

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, compatibility, xcode5

The [New Features in XCode 5](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012953-SW1) Section says that

> Xcode 5 requires a Mac running OS X v10.8.

Also the [Compatibility Sections](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/00-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004635-SW1) states that XCode 5 requires at least OS X 10.8.

Is there a way to install XCode 5 on a Macbook Pro (Core 2 Duo) running OS X 10.7?

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot, least version for installing XCode 5 is 10.8.4

Answer (score 1):

That does not give you ability to compile or simulate iOS7. Sometimes people are able to get the required libraries or installer to run on the older versions of MacOS... if anyone has any luck please share :)

Answer (score 0):

use older versions of Xcode. :) Like 4.6 for example.

Comment: Clarified the question. I want to install XCode 5.